# Repeating the same note n times

Tags: lilypond

#### Context

I'm new to lilypond and scheme, and for a score I need to repeat many times one single note (same pitch, same rythm). So I tried to implement a `(loopnote)` function, which takes an integer (number of repeats) and a note as arguments. This function is designed to work within `\relative` mode: when the given note has an octave modifier, it will keep it only for the first note, and reset it for all the others, in order to avoid out-of-control repeated octaves up.

#### Issue

But it does not work as expected:

- Note octaves are "often" demultiplied and go up very quickly, each time the second duplicated note is encountered;
- When I set an octave modifier for the relative mode e.g. `\relative c'`, things become worse: octaves go up even more quickly;
- When I store `\loopnote 16 c'` in a variable and use it, it works "better" than when if I use the function directly (but not in all cases, there are still problems with `\relative c'`).

When I use `\displayMusic`, I don't see any difference between `{ c' c c c }`, `\loopnote 4 c'` or `\myvar` (where `myvar = \loopnote 4 c'`).

What am I missing?

#### EDIT

When I wrote this question I was not aware of the command `\repeat unfold`, which is doing exactly what I want... However, this does not explain why my own code is not working, and how to fix it...

#### Source code and example images

Here is the lilypond source code which gave me the two images below:

```
\version "2.19.82"
\language "english"

#(define dup (lambda (el n) (if (= n 0) '() (cons el (dup el (- n 1))))))
#(define greaterThanZero? (lambda (val) (and (integer? val) (> val 0))))

loopnote = #(define-music-function
    (parser location n note) 
    (greaterThanZero?  ly:music?)

    (let (
            (noteCopy (ly:music-deep-copy note))
            (pitch (ly:music-property note 'pitch)))
        (let (
                (notename (ly:pitch-notename pitch))
                (alteration (ly:pitch-alteration pitch)))
            ; Reset pitch octave information for every note but the first:
            (set! (ly:music-property noteCopy 'pitch) (ly:make-pitch -1 notename alteration))
            (make-music 'SequentialMusic 'elements (cons note (dup noteCopy (- n 1)))))))

% EXAMPLE 1:

myvar = \loopnote 4 c'
\relative c {
    \myvar          % Working well
    \myvar          % Working well
    \loopnote 4 c   % Problem
}

% EXAMPLE 2:

% myvar = \loopnote 4 c
% \relative c' {
%   \myvar
%   \myvar
%   \myvar
%   \loopnote 4 c
%   \myvar
%   \myvar
%   \loopnote 4 c
% }
```

#### Example 1

[image: Lylipond example 1]

#### Example 2

[image: Lylipond example 2]